# IOS: Drawing best route path using google map

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have already integrated my IOS application with google map. I need to draw best route path (Less distance) from my current location to some (XYZ) destination using google map. And also I need to have that mode of transport (like : Drive, Walk, transport)

Can someone please help me to do this. any framework to draw line between two points(Best path draw) and navigate that path when I click on Drive (update the path in every 2 sec)

Comment: Check this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Answer (score 0):

**step 1**

Make an `URL request` to Google Directions `API`.

**step 2**

When you receive a `JSON file` go through all steps.

**step 3**

Decode the points objects.

---

first get all points coordinates which are coming on your route then add these points(latitude and longitude of that points) in path and you can will draw path according to that... try this:

```
GMSCameraPosition *position=[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:15.5203 longitude:68.8567 zoom:10];
_mView =[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:position];
_mView.myLocationEnabled=YES;
GMSMarker *marker=[[GMSMarker alloc]init];
marker.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(15.5203, 68.8567);
marker.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"] ;
marker.groundAnchor=CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
marker.map=_mView;
GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];   
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(@(15.520).doubleValue,@(68.856).doubleValue)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(@(15.7).doubleValue,@(73.8567).doubleValue)];

GMSPolyline *rect = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
rect.strokeWidth = 2.f;
rect.map = _mView;
self.view=_mView;
```

---

**Update**

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"%@?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=true&key=%@",
                       @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json",
                       mapView.myLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                       mapView.myLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                       destLatitude,
                       destLongitude,
                       @"Enter Google API String Here"];
NSURL *directionsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];


ASIHTTPRequest *req = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:directionsURL];
[req startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [req error];
if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [req responseString];
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
    NSDictionary *json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[req responseData] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    GMSPath *path =[GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:json[@"routes"][0][@"overview_polyline"][@"points"]];
    GMSPolyline *singleLine = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    singleLine.strokeWidth = 7;
    singleLine.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    singleLine.map = self.mapView;
}
else NSLog(@"%@",[req error]);
```

Comment: can you send me a link which will explain in brief about this please

Comment: check my updated answer bro.... and see this video also...  http://talkminer.com/viewtalk.jsp?videoid=AdV7bCWuDYg&q=&row=4&N=5#.Ui2H1mSAZTE

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But i have already done this. I need to have navigation of route from my current location to destination like we have in google map(Ex: Turn left after 10mtr etc). And also I need to refresh the map every 2 sec. Also I need know what Logic google map have to draw best path.

Comment: This seems to be little bit difficult. I just redirected my source and destination values to native map. Ex: UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSString *ourPath = @"http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=Cupertino&daddr=San+Francisco";
    NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
    [ourApplication openURL:ourURL];                                                          Now I need to add my India source and destination, but it will not take , operator in between the string. I am not able to give india cities location here. Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps You

```
NSString *originString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", origin.coordinate.latitude, origin.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *destinationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", destination.coordinate.latitude, destination.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *directionsAPI = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
    NSString *directionsUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&origin=%@&destination=%@&mode=driving", directionsAPI, originString, destinationString];
    NSURL *directionsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:directionsUrlString];


    NSURLSessionDataTask *fetchDirectionsTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:directionsUrl completionHandler:
                                                 ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                                 {
                                                     NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                                                     if(error)
                                                     {
                                                         if(completionHandler)
                                                             completionHandler(nil);
                                                         return;
                                                     }

                                                     NSArray *routesArray = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];

                                                     GMSPolyline *polyline = nil;
                                                     if ([routesArray count] > 0)
                                                     {
                                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                         NSDictionary *routeDict = [routesArray objectAtIndex:0];
                                                         NSDictionary *routeOverviewPolyline = [routeDict objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
                                                         NSString *points = [routeOverviewPolyline objectForKey:@"points"];
                                                 GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath: [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath: points]];
                                                         polyline.map = _mView;
                                                         polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:4/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0];
                                                         polyline.strokeWidth = 4.0f;
                                                             });
                                                         };


                                                     if(completionHandler)
                                                         completionHandler(polyline);
                                                 }];
    [fetchDirectionsTask resume];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your code? Just dumping code in here does not help people to learn.

Comment: its  a directionsAPI which give route  between  latitude and longitude you pass In it and draw route with the help of GMSPolyline